# Excel VBA - Trying to return values that that only contain all criteria

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, pivot, autofilter

Okay so this one is hard to explain - I have a very large table that has customers, part numbers, price, and revenue. I need to return all customers that use a list of part numbers; so for instance if they use parts ABC and DEF then it would return the customers that use those parts, and the revenue for those customers (I figured I would copy the entire rows to another table or something).

I don't want to see customers that use one part but not the other. I've tried doing autofilters and advanced filters with no luck, but I would rather do this in VBA if possible. I'm not sure which way would be the easiest...

One thought was to pivot the table and sort by customers, but this is very manual and I need to pull these results into another table so I can see the data separately. Any help is much appreciated!

## Example table

[image: Example Table]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your schema ??

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - the spreadsheet is very simple though: columns for customer, part number, cost, revenue, and some other erroneous data that I don't need. It's a huge table, but those are the important columns for my purposes. I have another sheet in the workbook where I have a list of parts that I want to use as filters, but I need to get the basic concept down before I scale it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarification. see added code

You can use the "xlFilterValues" operator of "AutoFilter()" method of "Range" object.

Assuming first row has headers, here's the "basic concepts" code you asked for:

```
Dim partListArr As Variant

With Worksheets("MyListSheetName")
     partListArr = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).Value)'<--| retrieve the content of its column A cells from row 1 down to its last not empty cell
End With

With Worksheets("MyDataSheetName")
     With .Range("Z1", .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its A to Z columns cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
         .Autofilter field:=2, Criteria1:=partListArray, operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter referenced range on its 2nd field with list of parts
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference filtered cells, skipping headers

            ' here your code to handle filtered cells

        End With
     End With
End With
```

---

Since your clarifications you could still use nested `AutoFilter()`s to catch proper customers sharing all listed parts, but it's more effective leaving this work to dictionaries and use `AutoFilter()` for the final copy/paste part. like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim custDict As Scripting.Dictionary, partDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim cust As Variant, part As Variant
    Dim parts As String
    Dim okCust As Boolean

    With Worksheets("MyListSheetName")
        Set partDict = GetList(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)))
    End With

    With Worksheets("MyDataSheetName")
         With .Range("Z1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its A to Z columns cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
            Set custDict = GetList(.Resize(.Rows.count, 1).Offset(1))

            For Each cust In custDict.Keys
                parts = custDict(cust) & "|"
                For Each part In partDict.Keys
                    okCust = InStr(parts, "|" & part & "|") > 0
                    If Not okCust Then Exit For
                Next part
                If okCust Then
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=cust
                    With .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference filtered cells, skipping headers
                        .Copy Destination:=GetSheet(CStr(cust)).Range("A1")
                    End With
                End If
            Next cust

         End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub

Function GetList(rng As Range) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        dict(cell.Value) = dict(cell.Value) & "|" & cell.Offset(, 1)
    Next cell

    Set GetList = dict
End Function

Function GetSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)

    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetSheet = Worksheets.Add
        GetSheet.Name = shtName
    Else
        GetSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I think I'm not explaining it very well (it's why I can't seem to find any solutions as is) - Once I have the filtered data, I want to copy customers that have all of the parts from the list into a new table, but only customers that have all of the parts. So for instance, customer A is using part 123 and customer B is using part 123 and 234, and I am looking for customers that use 123 and 234, so it would only return customer B. Does that make sense? Sorry if it's not 100% clear... Thanks for your help so far, this script does work to filter the data. One typo was the criteria is partListArr

Comment: Fantastic! I haven't been able to test yet, but will give an update tomorrow once I have time to implement. I just looking into dictionaries and this seems like a very elegant solution; I hadn't heard of the dictionary function yet, as my VBA experience is somewhat limited... Thanks in advance - will update soon.

Comment: to use `Dictionary` object with early binding (as per my code) you have to add its library reference to your project: in you VBA Ide click Tools-> References, scroll list till "Microsoft Scripting Runtime", click the check mark beside it and click "OK"

Comment: Okay I've run the code, and added a debug.print to see what is being added to the dictionary, and I see that it adds all of the part numbers to the part number dictionary and all of the customer names to the cust dictionary, but I don't see it adding the part numbers associated with those customers as values to the customer. I assume the way it would work is the customer is the key and the part numbers are the values and they're added together and separated by the " | " portion, but I don't see that happening. I'll try to grab a screenshot of my table as an example of the data.

Comment: Also, when I run the code it doesn't copy to the new worksheet per the autofilter portion, so I assume there is some issue with comparing the list and the customer values.

Comment: Okay I messed something up - it works perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: One last question - rather than put each customer on its own sheet, is there an easy way to put them all on one sheet? Some of these queries return 10+ results so it creates a lot of sheets! Thanks! I marked as answered.

Comment: I figured it out - I pass a value to name the sheet that is created, use lastrow = 1, then in the inner loop I copy to sheet.range("A" & lastrow), then set lastrow to range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Row and it simply pastes the next set to that row number.